# How to find all possible paths with as many edges between two same vertices?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, combinatorics

Suppose I have an undirected graph `G = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}]`

[image]

I used `FindPath[G,1,4,Infinity,All]` and obtained the result

> `{{1, 2, 3, 4}}`

But the expected result is

> `{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}}`

Is there any way to get all possible paths even though any number of edges are present in between two same vertices?

---

[Link to Wolfram Community cross post.](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/578430?p_p_auth=hSH9DAHo)

Comment: I don't have v10, so I can't test. But the standard way to do such things in graph theory is by creating a dummy vertex on each multiedge (or if you don't want to take care of it, on each edge) to differentiate them

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to get this out of the way: I would not consider this a bug. `FindPath` returns a sequence of vertices, not a sequence of edges, which indicates the definition of *path* that is meant here.  `{{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}}` are of course the very same sequence of vertices, regardless of any edges inbetween, thus there is no reason for `FindPath` to return them multiple times.

---

If needed, you can take the multiplicities of edges into account like this.

First convert to a list of edges:

```
FindPath[graph, 1, 4, Infinity, All]
path = First[%]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)

edgeSequence = Sort /@ UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[path, 2, 1]
(* {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4} *)

edgeMultiplicities = Counts[Sort /@ EdgeList[graph]]
(* <|1 <-> 2 -> 1, 2 <-> 3 -> 2, 3 <-> 4 -> 1|> *)

edgeMultiplicities /@ edgeSequence
(* {1, 2, 1} *)

Times @@ %
(* 2 *)
```

The result is that this path should be taken into account twice.

The `Sort` was necessary to canonicalize directed edges, and make sure that `1<->2` and `2<->1` are treated as the same.

Comment: Actually it won't work for `FindPath[graph, 4, 1, Infinity, All]` because of `edgeSequence` which defines objects like `4<->3` instead of `3<->4`. Also the graph could contain directed edges, so a more universal solution would be : `edgeSequence = Partition[path, 2, 1] ; edgeMultiplicities = 
 Counts[EdgeList[graph] /. {DirectedEdge -> List, 
    UndirectedEdge[a_, b_] :> Sequence[{a, b}, {b, a}]}]`. Then it will work even for cases like `Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 <-> 4}]`

Comment: @SquareOne Thank you, you are completely right.  Corrected now.  What's ridiculous about my mistake is that I posted this yesterday: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24581195#24581195  Actually I wonder why `DirectedEdges` isn't `Orderless` ...

Answer (score 2):

If the aim to count the paths of certain length [including traversing same vertices/edges multiple times: see comment Szabolcs]  (and it may not be) you could use `AdjacencyMatrix`, e.g.

```
g = Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}]
```

then

```
np[g_, i_, j_, n_] := MatrixPower[AdjacencyMatrix[g], n][[i, j]]
```

so `np[g,1,4,3]` yields 2, `np[g,2,2,3]` yields 0 (as would any odd number of steps)  but `np[g,2,2,4]` yields 29.

Comment: It's good to mention the usual caveat that this method does not exclude passing through the same vertices (or edges) multiple times.

Comment: @Szabolcs thank you...yes I should have been more precise in language. Will edit to be precise.